# Cannot format my SD card

Tags: format

I am new to Ubuntu, using 14.04 I am trying to format an SD card to make space on it, and it's not working. I tried in terminal:

```
format mmcblk0
hformat mmcblk0
```

and it says:

```
hformat: /home/michael/mmcblk0: error (no such file or directory)
```

How do you format an SD card?

Answer (score 14):

It's very easy.

1. First insert your SD in Sdcard Reader, let Ubuntu mount it.
   check the access path for the sd card using `df`
   You will get some output like this

   ```
   Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /dev/sda7      104087776 76247376  22529988  78% /
   /dev/sdd1       15549952    13056  15536896   1% /media/g/3630-6335
   ```
2. Unmount the sd  using

   ```
   sudo umount /path/to/sd/card
   ```
3. Format the card using `mkfs`

   ```
   sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -v /path/to/sd/card
   ```

-F flag is for Fat32 system.
-v flag is for being verbose

Comment: Hi. I just tried it and did not work, and i mount the partion as boot whit gpart, and it almost work, and it type in this at the startup I/O system error and mmcblk.

Comment: @Michael can you give some error log, of the commands you are trying ?

Comment: This works for me. `sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -v -I /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the included Disks application

[image]

Click on the target partition. Now you can create new partitions, format the disk or change partition type.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the software gparted to format the partition on your sd drive

1. Download gparted from the software centre
2. Start it
3. Load your sd within the software (upper right button)
4. right click on sd partition: unmount
5. Delete partition
6. Create new partition fat32, label it as you like

That's it, if you have any problem write here :)

Comment: Hi. I tried gpart but it says unable to read input / output error on mmcblk0.